# Forms in angular 2 with validaton

Tags: angular, ionic2

here I have tried some form validation code with angular 2 in ionic application I got some errors in that form can anybody explain.

here is the template

```
 <ion-item>
            <ion-label for="name" floating >FIRST NAME</ion-label>
            <ion-input formControlName="firstName" type="text" required></ion-input>
        <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
             class="alert alert-danger">
          Name is required
        </div>
        </ion-item>
```

I am getting Runtime error message in browser.

Comment: Please post the error message

Comment: Error in ./HomePage class HomePage- caused by: cannot read the property 'valid' of undefined

Comment: share your component code. you can try by adding `#name` to `ion-input`  like `<ion-input formControlName="firstName" type="text" #name required></ion-input>`

Comment: your  **name** is undefined and calling **name.valid** on undefined is causing the issue. Post your **class** also

Answer (score 0):

You should add a reference in your ion-input,  a name field (angular2 forms use them internally) and probably you need to bind this input to a property called name in your component.

Your html should be like this:

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-label for="name" floating >FIRST NAME</ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="firstName" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" type="text" #name="ngModel" required></ion-input>
        <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
             Name is required
        </div>
</ion-item>
```

And don't forget to add a property called "name" in your component. Like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'the-html-page-with-your-form',
})
export class YourComponent {
    name: string="";
    constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: Tell me where to add name in component

Comment: if you binding model like this, in this case name is not defined in component and this will throw error. if you define your name in component like `name: string = ""` this will not throw error but then validation will be ok. If you add some restriction like min length = 5 then you will see your error message

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this one!

```
<ion-item>
<ion-label floating >FIRST NAME</ion-label>
<ion-input formControlName="firstName" #refName class="form.control" type="text" ></ion-input>
    <div *ngIf='signupForm.control'[firstName].hasError('required') class="alert alert-danger">
                Please Enter Name!
    </div>
 </ion-item>
```

This Shows error like 'Template parse error'